# Safari and Chrome showing different results of new Date()

Tags: javascript

I understand this question sounds a little too silly but yes this is happening. When I tried in console doing

```js
  console.log(new Date("2017-05-22T00:00:00"))
```

Google chrome gives: `"Mon May 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"`

while **Safari** gives `"Mon May 22 2017 05:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)"`

why is there a difference of "**05:30:00**"?

This I am testing on the same machine with IST time zone.

Comment: Interesting, it looks like it's assuming the iso string is in UTC and converting it to your local timezone

Comment: I get "2017-05-21T22:00:00.000Z" in Chrome on OSX

Comment: I get "2017-05-22T00:00:00.000Z" in Chrome, Safari, and FF (on OS X).

Comment: And I am getting "Mon May 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" in chrome

Comment: me getting on chrome "Mon May 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)"

Comment: If I add .toString() I get `Mon May 22 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)` in Chrome OSX